# How to handle custom sql functions on schema update?

Tags: symfony, doctrine

Sometimes when you're looking for performance, you need to delegate some responsibilities to the database with some kind of complexity functions and triggers. I'd like to know what is the best practice to handle those custom sql functions to create/update when doctrine:schema:update command is called.

Comment: i would (and do) use [doctrine:migrations](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html).  You can edit the migrations files to do whatever you like.  These can then be run from cli.  Might be close to what youre looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The easier solution you have (I think) is to create your own command, do your logic inside, and call the `doctrine:schema:update` at end.

To do this, you can extend your command from the the [UpdateSchemaDoctrineCommand](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/blob/master/Command/Proxy/UpdateSchemaDoctrineCommand.php) or use a [Process](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html) in your command.

I prefer the first solution, also I will show you.

Create the command in `src/Acme/AppBundle/Command/CustomUpdateSchemaDoctrineCommand.php`
(for example, use one of your own bundles)

Then, extend it from the parent command like this :

```
<?php

namespace Acme\AppBundle\Command;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Command\Proxy\UpdateSchemaDoctrineCommand;

class CustomUpdateSchemaDoctrineCommand extends UpdateSchemaDoctrineCommand
{
    protected function configure()
    {
        parent::configure();

        $this->setName('custom:schema:update')
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        // Do your logic

        // Update your database schema
        return parent::execute($input, $output);

    }
}
```

If you need a tool that allow you to run SQL migrations, use the [DoctrineMigrationsBundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

I dont know way to realize automatically running other SQL-code, but you can use DoctrineMigration. It's run manualy, but you can write custom SQL and control versions - file contains creation date, used migrations names will be stored in DB.